# check if file exists in directory with .css extension based on social engine playlist title

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I'm struggling to wrap my head around some code im working on with a social engine based site. the basics of what I want to accomplish is to check if a file exists in a folder called /customcss/ for each playlist title with a .css extension. `$playlist->getTitle` is used to get the playlist title.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've been struggling with this for a few hours now, and since SE isnt open source, there is little info on the web.

Here is my code so far, which is not yeilding any error, but isnt working either...

```
<?php
$filename = '/customcss/$playlist->getTitle.css';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo 'official';
} else {
echo 'not official';
}
?>
```

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filename = '/customcss/'.$playlist->getTitle.'.css';
```

OR

```
$filename = "/customcss/{$playlist->getTitle}.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

$filename = '/customcss/$playlist->getTitle.css';
would pick from root

please use an absolute path

like

$filename = **_*DIR*_** . '/customcss/$playlist->getTitle.css';

Vicky Biswas